# Search mysql with two search terms

Tags: mysql, database

Totally new to mysql. 
I hope this is easy. 
Just want to search for results with

Fire AND poi in the field.

So this would exclude results with fire alone, or poi alone.

```
SELECT * FROM isc_products WHERE prodname like '%$search%' LIMIT 100
```

I tried the AND which brings back results with either.

Hope this makes sense and is an easy thing to achieve.

Thanks heaps
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat the whole condition. Not sure if this is what you were doing but the following will work.

```
SELECT * FROM isc_products 
WHERE prodname LIKE '%fire%' 
AND prodname LIKE '%poi%' LIMIT 100
```

btw; If you have both terms in one $string then you will need to separate them manually and format the query as above.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Already tried this. It returns results with either of those terms, not both. Is that the expected result?

Comment: This will only return rows where the words `fire` AND `poi` appear in the `prodname`

Comment: If a query isn't doing as you expect then make sure you echo out exactly what the finished query is before you execute it. You will quickly see where it is going wrong.

Comment: does `$search` contain both words? If so then you'd need to use something like `explode` to break up each word, which can then be appended to the query.

Comment: OK this is what i tried.
SELECT * FROM isc_products WHERE prodname LIKE '%$search%' AND prodname LIKE '%$search1%' LIMIT 100

The variables are coming from two search fields. So it's possible to add one term, or to refine, you can add two terms. 
see here. http://threeworlds.com.au/store/testproducts.php

Comment: it's still returning "either"

Comment: can you echo the query and post it in your question? Like trapper said, once you see exactly what is being sent to mysql it's easy to figure out where it's going wrong

Comment: sorry not sure how i do that. tried echo $result on 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM isc_products WHERE prodname LIKE '%$search%' OR prodname LIKE '%$search1%' LIMIT 100");

Comment: `echo "SELECT * FROM isc_products WHERE prodname LIKE '%$search%' OR prodname LIKE '%$search1%' LIMIT 100"; exit;`

Comment: btw; mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']) & mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search1']) prob what you want ;)

Comment: crap. not work with OR at all. AND works but as i said it's returning "either". This seems like it would be an easy and common task.

Comment: AND will work how you want it to, it seems that your problem is elsewhere, but you need to post the query in order for anyone to help you fix it :p

Comment: ok i got this as an echo as instructed above:
SELECT * FROM isc_products WHERE prodname LIKE '%fire%' AND prodname LIKE '%%' LIMIT 100. Looks like my second value is not passing through. 
FORM IS LIKE THIS: <form action="testproducts.php" method="post">
     <p> Search:<input type="text" value="" name="search" id="search">
     And <p> Search:<input type="text" value="" name="search1" id="search1">
     <input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
      
 </form>

Comment: wait, i think i found the problem.

Comment: YES! Got it. Forgot to set $search1 = $_POST['search1']. How clever. Thanks heaps for the super speed help!! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result containing one of the terms OR both, use that (replace search termns with your varaibles; split the given search termn by space character and then dynamically create the OR parts):

```
SELECT * FROM isc_products WHERE prodname LIKE '%fire%' OR prodname LIKE '%poi%' LIMIT 100
```